# Formula to write milliseconds in hh:mm:ss.000 format gives wrong values

Tags: arrays, datetime, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, number-formatting

I'm trying to convert duration in one column which is written in `milliseconds` (Ex: 600,2101,1110....) to `hh:mm:ss.000` format(Ex:00:00:00.600, 00:00:02.101...) using the below formula in google spreadsheets:

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(INT(A1/1000)/86400,"hh:mm:ss"),".",A1-(INT(A1/1000)*1000))
```

It gives correct values for almost all , but one type of values which is durations having '0' as their second digit (Eg: 2010,3056,1011).
When 0 is the second digit , the after decimal value in hh:mm:ss.000 is rounded to the third digit and 0 is ignored (Example row 1 and 2 in below table). But for other durations it gives right value(row 3).
I need a formula that works well on all type of values i.e `1080 → 00:00:01.080` and not `00:00:01.80` .
Can someone please help with this.

| Duration in milliseconds | hh:mm:ss.000 format |
| --- | --- |
| 1080 | 00:00:01.80 (wrong) |
| 2010 | 00:00:02.10 (wrong) |
| 1630 | 00:00:01.630 (correct) |

Comment: why not just `=A1/86400000` and format the cell: `hh:mm:ss.000`? and if you want the output to be text and not a number: `=TEXT(A1/86400000,"hh:mm:ss.000")`

Comment: What do you have in `C4`? (you use A1 and C4 in formula). Why not use `ROUND(A1,3)`? Are you using the operation on the wrong way?

Comment: Sorry updated C4 to A1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A="",,TEXT(A2:A/86400000, "hh:mm:ss.000")))
```

[image]